# Call to a member function delete() on null / AdminHomeController.php line 26:

Tags: php, function, authentication, laravel-5.3, crud

Using the multi_auth from laravel 5.3 im trying to make a delete/edit/update button.

Im trying to delete an user from the admin dashboard retrieving information from the users table.
Actually my first problem is with the destroy function.

**This is my destroy route:**

```
Route::get('{id}',[
    'as' => 'admin.destroy',
    'uses' => 'AdminHomeController@destroy'
]);
```

**This is my controller from admin:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\User;

class AdminHomeController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('admin.user');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $users = User::all();

        return view("admin-home")->with('users', $users);
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $users = User::find($id);
        $users->delete();

        Flash::error('El usuario ' . $users->name . '$ ha sido eliminado con exito!');
        return redirect()->route('admin-home');
    }
}
```

**View with delete button:**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8">
                @if (count($users) > 0)
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            Todos los Usuarios
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <table class="table table-striped user-table">
                                <thead>
                                    <th>Nombre:</th>
                                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
                                    <th>Email:</th>
                                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
                                    <th>Acciones:</th>
                                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    @foreach ($users as $user)
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td> 
                                            <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>  
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td> 
                                            <td>{{ $user->email }}</td> 
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td> 
                                            <td>    
                                                <a href="{{ route('users.destroy', $user->id) }}" onclick="return confirm('¿Seguro que  desea eliminar este Usuario?')"  class="btn btn-danger"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>  
                                            </td    >   
                                            <td>    
                                                <a href="{{ route('users.edit', $user->id) }}" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    @endforeach
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                    </div>
                @endif
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Thank you!

Comment: You didn't bother checking that User::find() returned anything

Answer (score 0):

Check $id in 

`$users = User::find($id);
$users->delete();`

Object $users is null because user didn't found in database or $id is incorrect

Comment: I have 2 users in the DB, with id: 1, 2.
I can see em in the view list of users, but it fails after i created the delete button

Comment: can you post "delete" button code? probably button missing id parameter

Comment: and one more think: try to use User::findOrFail($id) instead of find(), this will throw error if something will goes wrong

Comment: Edited main post with view, trying fidOrFail gives me this error: 
No query results for model [App\User].
But i actually have a model App\User; i can see a list of my users but without the delete button

Comment: Very strange. Did you override newQuery() method in your App\User or some default condition in your model? probably your model has default condition and when you trying to just find it, condition is working and can't find row with id=$id

Comment: @Julian Moreira Look what query is queried via: 

    $sql = User::where('id', '=', $id)->toSql();
    var_dump($sql);
And try to use Input::get('id') instead of $id from method argument

Comment: Use var_dump's in php everywhere :) it's basic but so efficient debugging approach, but don't forget to remove "guys" after solving problem

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with the code i found this usefull:
In the view i had 2 buttons the delete and the edit ones, i changed:

{{ route('users.destroy', $user->id) }}
{{ route('users.edit', $user->id) }}

for:

{{ url('users.destroy', $user->id) }}
{{ url('users.edit', $user->id) }}

And now i can see the buttons without any problems, the issue now is the same as before, the function destroy gives me an error.
This is the route that causes the error:

```
Route::get('{id}',[
    'as' => 'admin.destroy',
    'uses' => 'AdminHomeController@destroy'
]);
```

Error: No query results for model [App\User].

**This is my User model:**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

And still can't find the issue.. @edwardstock